# How to map text file content in array of structure in go?

Tags: arrays, go, text-files

I have a text file `data.txt`:

```
0,0123,"Value 1"
1,0456,"Value 2"
```

In Go I have defined struct:

```
type ChangeStatus struct {
  Nr1 string
  Nr2 string
  Category string
}
```

I am new to Go so I was wondering how can I read that text file and put each text file line into array of `ChangeStatus`?

Comment: You can't do that directly, but you can use the CSV reader that reads slices of strings, and create objects from them. see http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#NewReader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`csv.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Reader) for that, for [example](http://play.golang.org/p/hVt3bHKBUC):

```
func main() {
    status := []ChangeStatus{}
    f := strings.NewReader(text_file) //replace this with os.Open as needed
    //defer f.Close()
    r := csv.NewReader(f)
    for {
        if parts, err := r.Read(); err == nil {
            cs := ChangeStatus{parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]}
            status = append(status, cs)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", status)
}
```